# JavaScript invalid date from DateTime Picker

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a function that will create two dates using the result of an input with [Bootstrap DateTime Picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I need to compare both of them.

But my first value (`rtime`) always gives an invalid date. Where am I wrong?

Note: `stime` is not editable, the user only uses the DateTime Picker for `rtime` field.

```js
var stime = '28/11/2017 09:18:52';
var rtime = '04/12/2017 10:16:34'; 

var lastReturn = new Date(rtime);
var lastOut = new Date(stime);

if (lastReturn >= lastOut) { 
  console.log("This date is after than the other!");
}

console.log(rtime);
console.log(stime);
console.log(lastReturn);
console.log(lastOut);
```

This result shows that `LastOut` is an invalid date:

[image: this result shows that LastOut is an invalid date]

Comment: Have you printed out the dates and checked them? Which reasons has spoken for to create not an minimal runnable example?

Comment: @reporter just edited so you may see what happens :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format must be month/day/year, not day/month/year

That why you get invallid date on 28/11/2017 09:18:52 because there isn't a 28th month.

```js
console.log(new Date('28/11/2017 09:18:52'))
console.log(new Date('11/28/2017 09:18:52'))
```

Comment: Does it work if I use yyyy-mm-dd with the DateTime Picker?

Comment: presumably yes.

Answer (score 0):

The dates you're picking are probably Month/Day/Year. But your expected date is Day/Month/Year. For example, the date 04/12/2017 is returning April 12th instead of December 4th. You can use a regex on your string to replace and make it in the correct format.

Please check this snippet:

```js
var stime = "28/11/2017 09:18:52" //$("#movesend").val();
var rtime = "04/12/2017 10:16:34" //$("#moveretorna").val(); 

function parseDate(dateString) {
    return dateString.replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3");
}

var lastReturn= new Date(parseDate(rtime));
var lastOut= new Date(parseDate(stime));

if(lastReturn>= lastOut)
{ 
   console.log("This date is after than the other!");
}

console.log(stime);
console.log(rtime);
console.log(lastReturn);
console.log(lastOut);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your date from `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format to `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format.

For conversion, you can use `string#replace`.

```js
var stime = '28/11/2017 09:18:52';
var rtime = '04/12/2017 10:16:34'; 

stime = stime.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(.*)/, '$2/$1/$3');
rtime = rtime.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(.*)/, '$2/$1/$3');

var lastReturn = new Date(rtime);
var lastOut = new Date(stime);

if (lastReturn >= lastOut) { 
  console.log("This date is after than the other!");
}

console.log(rtime);
console.log(stime);
console.log(lastReturn);
console.log(lastOut);
```

Comment: Will it work if I use yyyy-mm-dd or only MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS in JavaScript?